# Angular 2 - ng-bootstrap tooltips aren't positioned correctly for interpolated content in hybrid app

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Right now I'm running into a problem that I can't reproduce in plnkr, but basically - ng-bootstrap tooltips that have interpolated values aren't positioned correctly - they are shifted down and to the right.

[image: see image]

This only happens if the trigger mode is `mouseover, mouseenter, mouseleave`, or any combination of these. If it's `click` then it's positioned correctly. I am using Angular 2 downgraded components in Angular 1.4.

I think I've narrowed it down to the fact that tooltip content that require using `ng-content` don't have dimensions at initial runtime, thus we can't use those dimensions to correctly place the tooltips. My thought is to manually generate tooltips in `ngOnInit()`, but I'm not sure how. Not sure if this is a bug or just undocumented.

```
<template #tpl>
   hi {{play}}
</template>
<div [ngbTooltip]="tpl" container="body" placement="bottom">
  This tooltip is positioned correctly
</div>
<template #tpl2>
   hi {{play}}
</template>
<div [ngbTooltip]="tpl2" container="body" placement="bottom">
  [This tooltip is not positioned correctly][1]
</div>
```

where `play` is just some random text defined in the component.

A more practical example:

```
<template #tooltipTemplate >
  <div *ngFor="let p of data">
    <i [ngClass]="p.property1" [style.color]=" p.property2"></i>
    <span class="class1">{{p.value}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Somehow it's not getting the size of the tooltip until after it opens, so the offsets are wrong

-edit-

updated with plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/ysDNCSbtndD4BrQhWq8g?p=preview

Comment: There is little hope of helping you if you can't reproduce this in plunker....

Comment: it seems to be the same issue as this https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1398

Even though that's a different plugin, I think the underlying cause is the same

Comment: you are just speculating here with no evidence... Provide a minimal reproduce scenario in a plunker or similar and we will know what is going on. Otherwise I doubt anyone will be able to answer your question / help you.

Comment: I don't think I'm speculating, as the behavior is exactly the same across both these libraries, and both work perfectly fine in a pure Angular 2 environment. I can try to create a plunkr, but is there a cdn version of ng-bootstrap I could use? I could only find one for ng2-bootstrap

Comment: I meant "speculating" in respect to the underlying root cause. And yes, of course you can use ng-bootstrap in plunker (in fact you can fork working plunks from our demo page (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip). Here is a plunker that you could use as a starting point: http://plnkr.co/edit/XCBnpLrlo0koiN1LG8FV?p=preview

Comment: finally got it to work - http://plnkr.co/edit/ysDNCSbtndD4BrQhWq8g?p=preview